# Aggregate funciton to pandas groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I want to write a query which counts the number of planets in each solar system where the corresponding stars are larger than our sun (i.e. their radius is larger than 1).

Your query should return the star's radius and its number of planets, showing only rows where the number of planets is more than one. The result should be sorted in descending order based on the star radii.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_star = pd.read_csv("stars.csv",names=["kepler_id","t_eff","radius"])
df_planet = pd.read_csv("planets.csv",names=["kepler_id","koi_name","kepler_name","status","period","radius","t_eq"])

df_star[df_star["radius"]>1].merge(df_planet,on="kepler_id").groupby("radius_x",sort=True).count()
```

I am having the following result 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But I only want to return with a count bigger than 1.

I have also tried

```
agg({'kepler_id': lambda x: len(x>1)})
```

The data from Planets is: (sample)

```
10666592,K00002.01,Kepler-2 b,CONFIRMED,2.204735365,16.39,2025
6922244,K00010.01,Kepler-8 b,CONFIRMED,3.522498573,14.83,1521
11904151,K00072.01,Kepler-10 b,CONFIRMED,0.837491331,1.45,1968
10187017,K00082.04,Kepler-102 c,CONFIRMED,7.07136076,0.58,723
10187017,K00082.05,Kepler-102 b,CONFIRMED,5.28695437,0.49,797
10984090,K00112.02,Kepler-466 c,CONFIRMED,3.709213846,1.24,1236
9579641,K00115.01,Kepler-105 b,CONFIRMED,5.41220713,3.28,1306
9579641,K00115.02,Kepler-105 c,CONFIRMED,7.12594591,1.88,1191
9579641,K00115.03,,CANDIDATE,3.4358789,0.65,1519
8395660,K00116.01,Kepler-106 c,CONFIRMED,13.57076622,2.35,796
8395660,K00116.02,Kepler-106 e,CONFIRMED,43.84444353,2.58,538
8395660,K00116.03,Kepler-106 b,CONFIRMED,6.16491696,0.85,1035
8395660,K00116.04,Kepler-106 d,CONFIRMED,23.9802348,0.99,658
10875245,K00117.02,Kepler-107 c,CONFIRMED,4.90143807,1.84,1263
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO6Cw.png
```

And for Stars (sample of the big file)

```
2713049,5996,0.956
3114167,5666,0.677
3115833,5995,0.847
3246984,5735,0.973
3342970,6167,1.064
3351888,5717,1.057
3453214,5733,0.77
3641726,5349,0.82
3832474,5485,0.867
3935914,5934,0.893
3940418,5170,0.807
4049131,4905,0.761
4139816,3887,0.48
4275191,5557,0.781
4476123,5413,0.751
5358241,6079,0.945
5358624,5071,0.788
5456651,4980,0.734
6862328,5796,0.871
6922244,6225,1.451
```

Comment: Please post your input data in a copypastable format.

Comment: Can you explain in words what it is you are looking to do?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `radius_x`? Do two stars that do have the same radius not count as two separate stars?

Comment: Not. Radius in stars are relative to sun and in planets are relative to earh.